# Why spark.ml don't implement any of spark.mllib algorithms?

Tags: machine-learning, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Following the [Spark MLlib Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-guide.html)  we can read that Spark has two machine learning libraries:

- `spark.mllib`, built on top of RDDs.
- `spark.ml`, built on top of Dataframes.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31453324/which-is-efficient-dataframe-or-rdd-or-hiveql) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31508083/difference-between-dataframe-and-rdd-in-spark) question on StackOverflow, Dataframes are better (and newer) than RDDs and should be used whenever possible.

The problem is that I want to use common machine learning algorithms (e.g: [Frequent Pattern Mining](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html),[Naive Bayes](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-naive-bayes.html), etc.) and `spark.ml` (for dataframes) don't provide such methods, only `spark.mllib`(for RDDs) provides this algorithms.

If Dataframes are better than RDDs and the referred guide recommends the use of `spark.ml`, why aren't common machine learning methods implemented in that lib?

#### What's the missing point here?

Comment: Also related to [Saving models](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027767/save-ml-model-for-future-usage) in StackOverflow

Comment: This question is in fact interesting and as a matter of fact, it's related to the one mentioned by Alberto. You can find your answer within @zero323 's answer.

Comment: Late to the party, just wanted to add that though the main Spark ML online documentation doesn't mention it, you can find NaiveBayes within the API doc and you can certainly use it.  I am.

Answer (score 15):

**Spark 2.0.0**

Currently Spark moves strongly towards `DataFrame` API with ongoing deprecation of RDD API. While number of native "ML" algorithms is growing the main points highlighted below are still valid and internally many stages are implemented directly using RDDs.

See also: [Switch RDD-based MLlib APIs to maintenance mode in Spark 2.0](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Switch-RDD-based-MLlib-APIs-to-maintenance-mode-in-Spark-2-0-td17033.html)

**Spark < 2.0.0**

I guess that the main missing point is that `spark.ml` algorithms in general don't operate on DataFrames. So in practice it is more a matter of having a `ml` wrapper than anything else. Even native ML implementation (like [`ml.recommendation.ALS`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/recommendation/ALS.scala#L478) use `RDDs` internally).

Why not implement everything from scratch on top of DataFrames? Most likely because only a very small subset of machine learning algorithms can actually benefit from the optimizations which are currently implemented in Catalyst not to mention be efficiently and naturally implemented using DataFrame API / SQL.

- Majority of the ML algorithms require efficient linear algebra library not a tabular processing. Using cost based optimizer for linear algebra could be an interesting addition (I think that [flink](/questions/tagged/flink) already has one) but it looks like for now there is nothing to gain here.
- DataFrames API gives you very little control over the data. <s>You cannot use partitioner</s>*, you cannot access multiple records at the time (I mean a whole partition for example), you're limited to a relatively small set of types and operations, you cannot use mutable data structures and so on.
- Catalyst applies local optimizations. If you pass a SQL query / DSL expression it can analyze it, reorder, apply early projections. All of that is that great but typical scalable algorithms require iterative processing. So what you really want to optimize is a whole workflow and DataFrames alone are not faster than plain RDDs and depending on an operation can be actually slower.
- Iterative processing in Spark, especially with joins, requires a fine graded control over the number of partitions, otherwise [weird things happen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31659404/1560062). DataFrames give you no control over partitioning. Also, `DataFrame` / `Dataset` <s>don't provide native checkpoint capabilities</s> (fixed in Spark 2.1) which makes iterative processing almost impossible without ugly hacks
- Ignoring low level implementation details some groups of algorithms, like  FPM, don't fit very well into a model defined by ML pipelines.
- Many optimizations are limited to native types, not UDT extensions like `VectorUDT`.

There is one more problem with DataFrames, which is not really related to machine learning. When you decide to use a DataFrame in your code you give away almost all benefits of static typing and type inference. It is highly subjective if you consider it to be a problem or not but one thing for sure, it doesn't feel natural in Scala world.

Regarding better, newer and faster I would take a look at [Deep Dive into Spark SQL’s Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html), in particular the part related to quasiquotes:

> The following figure shows that quasiquotes let us generate code with performance similar to hand-tuned programs.

---

* This has been changed in Spark 1.6 but it is still limited to default `HashPartitioning`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think even if `ml` is used solely as a wrapper around `mllib`, it provides a large benefit for python users because `ml` will use the Scala version of `mllib` instead of the python version available through the `pyspark.mllib` API. This removes a large overhead of moving data between JVM and Python interpreter.

Comment: @Max If you stat with data loaded into Java objects and never move it back then yes. Otherwise it won't be different. There are also different kinds of "moving data" between VMs. So I am not sure if I understand the question.

Comment: Yes, I meant if your input / ouput is going to be on disk, and you use DataFrame API for disk I/O. 

As for movement between VMs, I just realized there's no need to serialize/deserialize data in the `pyspark.mllib` scenario (since the bulk of the data will forever remain in python VM as numpy arrays etc. and won't need to be operated on in the JVM). So I guess the overhead of using python RDDs vs Scala RDDs is limited to the issues you described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32471016/336527) - still it's not completely trivial I think?

Comment: @max Well... There is of course a benefit of keeping things in a single place. But all depends on the context. Typically distributed model training is way more expensive than any serde activity.  But you won't optimize by making faster a small fraction of the code. So be reasonable here I guess.