# Spark RDD groupByKey + join vs join performance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark on the cluster which I am sharing with others users. So it is not reliable to tell which one of my code runs more efficient just based on the running time. Because when I am running the more efficient code, someone else maybe running huge data works and makes my code executes for a longer time.

So can I ask 2 questions here:

1. I was using `join` function to join 2 `RDDs`and I am trying to use `groupByKey()` before using `join`, like this:

   ```
   rdd1.groupByKey().join(rdd2)
   ```

   seems that it took longer time, however I remember when I was using Hadoop Hive, the group by made my query ran faster. Since Spark is using lazy evaluation, I am wondering whether `groupByKey` before `join` makes things faster
2. I have noticed Spark has a SQL module, so far I really don't have time to try it, but can I ask what are the differences between the SQL module and RDD SQL like functions?

Comment: In the future please don't post two questions at the same time.

Comment: I don't think it's too late to edit out the second question. @Cherry Wu, would you be okay with that?

Comment: do you expect duplicate keys in both in rdd1 and rdd2?

Comment: @DanielDarabos, I don't mind if you add the second question. I found Spark SQL description http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html, `Spark SQL is a Spark module for structured data processing. Unlike the basic Spark RDD API, the interfaces provided by Spark SQL provide Spark with more information about the structure of both the data and the computation being performed. Internally, Spark SQL uses this extra information to perform extra optimizations.` Here, I guess "more info" means data is organized like relational data table

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. There is no good reason for `groupByKey` followed by `join` to be faster than `join` alone. If `rdd1` and `rdd2` have no partitioner or partitioners differ then a limiting factor is simply shuffling required for `HashPartitioning`.

   By using `groupByKey` you not only increase a total cost by keeping mutable buffers required for grouping but what is more important you use an additional transformation which results in a more complex DAG. `groupByKey` + `join`:

   ```
   rdd1 = sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("a", 3), ("b", 2)])
   rdd2 = sc.parallelize([("a", 5), ("c", 6), ("b", 7)])
   rdd1.groupByKey().join(rdd2)
   ```

   [image]

   vs. `join` alone:

   ```
   rdd1.join(rdd2)
   ```

   [image]

   Finally these two plans are not even equivalent and to get the same results you have to add an additional `flatMap` to the first one.
2. This is a quite broad question but to highlight the main differences:

   - `PairwiseRDDs` are homogeneous collections of  arbitrary`Tuple2` elements. For default operations you want key to be hashable in a meaningful way otherwise there are no strict requirements regarding the type. In contrast DataFrames exhibit much more dynamic typing but each column can only contain values from a [supported set of defined types](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.package). It is possible to define [UDT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32440461/1560062) but it still has to be expressed using basic ones.
   - DataFrames use a [Catalyst Optimizer](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/04/13/deep-dive-into-spark-sqls-catalyst-optimizer.html) which generates logical and physical execution planss and can generate highly optimized queries without need for applying manual low level optimizations. RDD based operations simply follow dependency DAG. It means worse performance without custom optimization but much better control over execution and some potential for fine graded tuning.

Some other things to read:

- [Difference between DataFrame and RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31508083/1560062)
- [Why spark.ml don't implement any of spark.mllib algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33237096/1560062)

Answer (score 4):

I mostly agree with zero323's answer, but I think there *is* reason to expect `join` to be faster after `groupByKey`. `groupByKey` reduces the amount of data and partitions the data by the key. Both of these help with the performance of a subsequent `join`.

I don't think the former (reduced data size) is significant. And to reap the benefits of the latter (partitioning) you need to have the other RDD partitioned the same way.

For example:

```
val a = sc.parallelize((1 to 10).map(_ -> 100)).groupByKey()
val b = sc.parallelize((1 to 10).map(_ -> 100)).partitionBy(a.partitioner.get)
a.join(b).collect
```

[image: DAG visualization]

Comment: It looks like in PySpark it is a difference between union followed by partitioning (`join` alone) vs partitioning followed by union (`groupByKey` + `join`  with partitioned `b`). I am not sure if there is something to gain.

Comment: Ah, you're right. But it may be the case that your other RDD is already partitioned the right way, so you don't have to count the cost of that work. At least that's what very often happens for us.