# Does spark's distinct() function shuffle only the distinct tuples from each partition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

As I understand distinct() hash partitions the RDD to identify the unique keys.  But does it optimize on moving only the distinct tuples per partition?

Imagine an RDD with the following partitions

1. [1, 2, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2]
2. [1, 3, 3, 5, 4, 5, 5, 5]

On a distinct on this RDD, would all the duplicate keys (2s in partition 1 and 5s in partition 2) get shuffled to their target partition or will only the distinct keys per partition get shuffled to the target?

If all keys get shuffled then an aggregate() with set() operations will reduce the shuffle.

```
def set_update(u, v):
    u.add(v)
    return u
rdd.aggregate(set(), set_update, lambda u1,u2: u1|u2)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`unique` is implemented via  `reduceByKey` on `(element, None)` pairs. So it shuffles only unique values per partition. If number of duplicates is low it is still quite expensive operation though.

There are situations when using `set` can be useful. In particular if you call `distinct` on `PairwseRDD` you may prefer to `aggregateByKey` / `combineByKey` instead to achieve both deduplication and partitioning by key at the same time. In particular consider following code:

```
rdd1 = sc.parallelize([("foo", 1), ("foo", 1), ("bar", 1)])
rdd2 = sc.parallelize([("foo", "x"), ("bar", "y")])
rdd1.distinct().join(rdd2)
```

It has to shuffle `rdd1` twice - once for `distinct` and once for `join`. Instead you can use `combineByKey`:

```
def flatten(kvs):
    (key, (left, right)) = kvs
    for v in left:
        yield (key, (v, right))

aggregated = (rdd1
    .aggregateByKey(set(), set_update, lambda u1, u2: u1 | u2))

rdd2_partitioned = rdd2.partitionBy(aggregated.getNumPartitions())

(aggregated.join(rdd2_partitioned)
    .flatMap(flatten))
```

**Note**:

`join` logic is a little bit different in Scala than in Python (PySpark is using `union` followed by `groupByKey`, see [Spark RDD groupByKey + join vs join performance](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33323422/1560062) for Python and Scala DAGs), hence we have to manually partition the second `RDD` before we call join.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Can you please elaborate on use of distinct() on PairwiseRDD?

Comment: Thanks. It took me a minute to understand. For everyone's benefit, notice that distinct() hash partitions by (k,v) and join partitions by (k). distinct() followed by join() therefore requires 2 shuffles. Instead, aggregateByKey partitions by (k) and subsequent join benefits from already hashed RDD.