# Column features must be of type org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.VectorUDT

Tags: apache-spark, import, pyspark

I want to run this code in pyspark (spark 2.1.1):

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA

bankPCA = PCA(k=3, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures") 
pcaModel = bankPCA.fit(bankDf)    
pcaResult = pcaModel.transform(bankDF).select("label", "pcaFeatures")    
pcaResult.show(truncate= false)
```

But I get this error:

> requirement failed: Column features must be of type
>   `org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vect orUDT@3bfc3ba7`  but was actually
>   `org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.VectorUDT@f71b0bce`.

Answer (score 3):

Example that you can find [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/ml-features.html#pca):

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors

data = [(Vectors.sparse(5, [(1, 1.0), (3, 7.0)]),),
    (Vectors.dense([2.0, 0.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0]),),
    (Vectors.dense([4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 7.0]),)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["features"])

pca = PCA(k=3, inputCol="features", outputCol="pcaFeatures")
model = pca.fit(df)

... other code ...
```

As you can see above, *df* is a dataframe which contains Vectors.sparse() and Vectors.dense() that are imported **from pyspark.ml.linalg**.

Probably, your **bankDf** contains Vectors imported **from pyspark.mllib.linalg**.

So you have to set that Vectors in your dataframes are imported

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
```

instead of:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vectors
```

Maybe you can find interesting this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33237096/why-spark-ml-dont-implement-any-of-spark-mllib-algorithms).