# Efficiently convert edge list to adjacency list using MapReduce

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, mapreduce, distributed-system

I have a list of directed edges which represent a tree. 'u v' means u is a child of v.

```
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
lines = sc.textFile("/content/sample_data/data.txt")
lines.take(10)
```

```
['0 0', '1 0', '2 0', '3 1', '4 1', '5 2', '6 2', '7 3', '8 3', '9 4']
```

I converted the above to the following form stored as `intermediate`:

```
[(0, ('out', 0)),
 (0, ('in', 0)),
 (1, ('out', 0)),
 (0, ('in', 1)),...]
```

I am trying to build an adjacency list of the form from the above:

```
[(8721, [('out', 4360), ('in', 17443), ('in', 17444)]),
 (9291, [('out', 4645), ('in', 18583), ('in', 18584)]),
 (9345, [('out', 4672), ('in', 18691), ('in', 18692)]),..]
```

Here, First row tells that 8721 is a child of 4360 and [17443, 17444] are children of 8721

I am using `groupByKey` or `reduceByKey` methods exposed by the Spark module.

```
intermediate.groupByKey().mapValues(list)
```

Above line is taking a lot of time. It is taking almost 250 seconds for 100 MB of test data on 8-core machine with 12 GB RAM. I have to eventually deploy it for >15GB data on distributed environment.

I understand that groupByKey causes shuffling of data across all nodes. Is there any way to avoid it in my case ?
Any suggestions on how to optimise this operation is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't avoid shuffle as you're grouping rows of your dataset. However, you can use dataframe API instead of RDDs. Dataframe API is more performant than RDDs, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31474032/6807769)

If your txt file is in a form as follows:

```
0 0
0 1
...
```

Then you can read it as a dataframe.

```py
df = spark.read.csv('test.txt', sep=' ')
df.show()

+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|
+---+---+
|  0|  0|
|  1|  0|
|  2|  0|
|  3|  1|
|  4|  1|
|  5|  2|
|  6|  2|
|  7|  3|
|  8|  3|
|  9|  4|
+---+---+
```

Do cross join or unionAll by attaching the type column:

```
df2 = df.withColumn('_c2', f.lit('in')).unionAll(df.select('_c1', '_c0').withColumn('_c2', f.lit('out')))
df2.show()

+---+---+---+
|_c0|_c1|_c2|
+---+---+---+
|  0|  0| in|
|  1|  0| in|
|  2|  0| in|
|  3|  1| in|
|  4|  1| in|
|  5|  2| in|
|  6|  2| in|
|  7|  3| in|
|  8|  3| in|
|  9|  4| in|
|  0|  0|out|
|  0|  1|out|
|  0|  2|out|
|  1|  3|out|
|  1|  4|out|
|  2|  5|out|
|  2|  6|out|
|  3|  7|out|
|  3|  8|out|
|  4|  9|out|
+---+---+---+
```

and `groupBy` the result.

```py
df3 = df2.groupBy('_c0').agg(f.collect_list(f.array('_c2','_c1'))).toDF('edge', 'list')
df3.show(truncate=False)
df3.printSchema()

+----+---------------------------------------+
|edge|list                                   |
+----+---------------------------------------+
|7   |[[in, 3]]                              |
|3   |[[in, 1], [out, 7], [out, 8]]          |
|8   |[[in, 3]]                              |
|0   |[[in, 0], [out, 0], [out, 1], [out, 2]]|
|5   |[[in, 2]]                              |
|6   |[[in, 2]]                              |
|9   |[[in, 4]]                              |
|1   |[[in, 0], [out, 3], [out, 4]]          |
|4   |[[in, 1], [out, 9]]                    |
|2   |[[in, 0], [out, 5], [out, 6]]          |
+----+---------------------------------------+

root
 |-- edge: string (nullable = true)
 |-- list: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```